# Google Tag Manager access datalayer object values

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to access datalayer variables on add to cart event but it does not get tracked on the tag manager admin site

*The event is triggered but the values are not send

Datalayer push:

```
<script>
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'addToCart', 
    'ecommerce': {
      'currencyCode': 'EUR', 
      'add': {
        'products': [
          {
            'name': 'test',
            'id': 'ZZZ232323',
            'price': 33,
            'brand': '',
            'category': 'test',
            'variant': '','quantity': 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

And i'm trying to access the datalayer to get the product name using:

```
dataLayer.find(x => x.event == 'addToCart').ecommerce.add.products[dataLayer.find(x => x.event == 'addToCart').ecommerce.add.products.length - 1].price
```

[Image of google tag manager site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgd3n.png)

Answer (score 1):

Data Layer Variables don't need to reference a specific step (array element) of the dataLayer. When you create a reference to a dataLayer variable, e.g. `ecommerce`, Google Tag Manager (GTM) will try to evaluate it at any given GTM event, but will fall back to `undefined`, or any other value, you specify.

This means, that if you fire your Facebook Pixel tracking code when the product data gets available (event = addToCart), a proper reference to the ecommerce data will have value in it. There are several options to get your product name.

You can create a general 'Ecommerce' variable, referencing `ecommerce` as Data Layer Variable Name. In your Facebook Pixel related code you will have to walk to the desired variable, and also take care for any possible missing values. However, this ecommerce variable can be used in several tags.

```
var productName = {{Ecommerce}}.add.products[0].name; //assuming you'll always have just one product in products array
```

Or, you can go for a specific variable, where your set 'Ecommerce - name of product added to cart', where you reference `ecommerce.add.products[0].name`. This way, you can simply assign this variable to the proper Facebook Pixel variable, using `{{Ecommerce - name of product added to cart}}`